# Stack Smashing Error using C9.io and C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting a Stack Smashing Error using the c9 compiler, and I looked up reasons for the error, which is supposedly buggy code/passing variables or something that isn't declared/initialized, but I cant find the error in my code...

I've stripped the following code of any unnecessary code that doesn't pertain to the error, and this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void checkWord(char *word, int size);

int main () {
    string word1 = "racecar";
    char wordArr[sizeof(word1)];
    strcpy(wordArr, word1.c_str());
    checkWord(wordArr, strlen(wordArr));

    string word2 = "something";
    char word2Arr[sizeof(word2)];
    strcpy(word2Arr, word2.c_str());
    checkWord(word2Arr, strlen(word2Arr));
}

void checkWord(char *wordArr, int size) {
    // cout << "Size1: " << size << endl;
    int workingSize;
    if ((size % 2) != 0) {
        workingSize = (size +1)/2;
    } else {
        workingSize = size/2;
    }
    char *p, *q;
    p = wordArr;
    q = wordArr+strlen(wordArr)-1;
    bool pal = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < workingSize; i++) {
        if (*p != *q) {
            pal = false;
        }
        p++;
        q--;
    }
}
```

Which gives me this error output:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***:/home/ubuntu/workspace/.c9/metadata/workspace/3_16Lab2.cpp.o terminated
bash: line 12: 48077 Aborted                 $file.o $args


Process exited with code: 134
```

Otherwise, the program executes without any issue and, in this instance, confirms whether or not the words "racecar" and "something" are palindromes or not.

Comment: The conversion from `string` to `char*` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `char wordArr[sizeof(word1)];` which is one char short. Sizeof gives the number of characters in the string, but you need one more for the trailing `'\0'`.

As a consequence, you start overwriting memory that you don't own, and anything beyond that is random undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(word1)` returns the number of bytes the variable `word1` occupies, which has nothing to do with the length of the string it represents.  You should use `word1.length() + 1` to get the length of the string, including the terminating nul character.  (Same of `sizeof(word2)`.)

A better solution would be to either change `checkWord` to take its first parameter as a `const char *wordArr`, and pass the word in using `word1.c_str()`, or just pass the string to `checkWord` and not use character pointers at all.